# How to round to n decimal places in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to round my variables:

I have: "5.853"  -> I expect:"5.85"

I have: "27.285" -> I expect:"27.29"

I have: "27.284" -> I expect:"27.28"

None of the `RoundingMode` type doesn't work.

```
String volume = "5.853"; //or 27.285 or 27.284
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
String value = df.format(Float.valueOf(volume));
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: What other modes did you try?

Comment: Did you try [`HALF_UP`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP)? What results did you observe?

Comment: Did you check to see what `Float.valueOf(volume)` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `DecimalFormat` :

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("5.853").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("27.285").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("27.284").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

[Live demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/krP)

Answer (score 2):

You've succumbed to *round-off error*: Your float values aren't *exactly* what you think (because they can't be represented exactly), so the value being rounded isn't exactly what you think.  As @khelwood says, `HALF_UP` should do what what you (seem to) want, but because 27.285 can't be represented exactly, it gets rounded as if it were 27.2849.